# Threading / Queue in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I intend using threads/queues with python 2.5.2
But it seems that python becomes freezed at the queue.join()-command.
The output of the followong code is only: BEFORE

```
import Queue
import threading

queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:

            i = self.queue.get()
            print i
            self.queue.task_done()


def main():

    for i in range(5):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    for i in range(5):
        queue.put(i)

    print "BEFORE"
    queue.join()
    print "AFTER"


main()
```

Has someone an idea about what is going wrong?

Comment: queue.put(1) ... not saying this is the solution. But just check the id(queue) is same across all functions ... if not then use global queue in function ...

Comment: this works just fine for me with Python 2.6.6 on Windows

Comment: This code looks pretty flawless, and I read this kinda stuff all day :\

Comment: @Eli - I don't think that was a copy-paste error, I think that was his real error.

Comment: @agf: hmm, if that's so, good catch :)

Comment: Your `run` method is nested inside your `__init__` method. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Eli Nice article by the way, I especially liked footnote #7 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the `t.setDaemon(True)` part.

So in Python > 2.6, use:

```
t.setDaemon(True)
```

And in Python < 2.6, use:

```
t.daemon = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You run() method on your ThreadUrl class is indented too far.  The thread is never started as a result.  If you put the indention of the run method at the same indentation level as **init**() it'll work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But now after calling the queue.put(i)-command the first (or sometimes a second) time python crashes.... !?

Comment: Crashes how?  A standard exception or it dies with a signal (SEGV)?

Comment: IDLE freezes and then the window becomes closed by the task manager.

Comment: There might be issues with threading in old versions of IDLE. I think it is resolved in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I now found is:

**Don't use Python 2.5.2!
If one uses Python 2.7.2 instead the code above works very well.**

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Use Daemon=True. That will ensure that your thread exits once the main function is executed.