# Multithreaded MD5 Checksum in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, md5, checksum

I have a python script that recursively walks a specified directory, and checksums each file it finds. It then writes a log file which lists all file paths and their md5 checksums.

Sequentially, this takes a long time for 50,000 files at 15 MB each.  However, my computer has much more resources available than it's actually using.  How can I adjust my approach so that the script uses more resources to execute faster?

For example, could I split my file list into thirds and run a thread for each, giving me a 3x runtime?

I'm not very comfortable with threading, and I hope someone wouldn't mind whipping up and example for my case.

Here's the code for my sequential md5 loop:

```
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(root_path):
    for filename in files:
        file_path = root + "/" + filename
        md5_pairs.append([file_path, md5file(file_path, 128)])
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The simplest way would be to just launch separate instances of your python script, where each one is given a subtree from the root_path

Comment: Before attepting any optimization, it is a good idea to investigate first where the bottlenecks are. For instance, if MD5 takes significantly less than reading the file from disk, don't expect too much in term of speed up.

Comment: This is a great point, I benchmarked simple reads vs checksums, and checksumming added only about 10% to the runtime.  Our Fibre connected SAN reads at 8 Gb/s.  I would think I could get those files to read in faster, no? To read 600 files totalling 7 GB, it takes 88 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help!  Stack Overflow is awesome!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of work, I think multiprocessing.Pool would give you less surprises - 
check the examples and docs at http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Hi jsbueno,  I tried using pool as suggested, but it only improved runtime by 20%.  Could this be better?  Since I'm working with lots of small files is it better to split the file list into chunks and send each chunk to the pool?  Or is it best to send each individual md5 call to the pool?

Comment: The reason you're not seeing a greater than 20% speedup might indicate your processing is IO bound instead of CPU bound. You should do some profiling to see if this is the case, since in theory you should be able to get 100% efficiency on the compute portion.

Comment: if it is io bound you might be able to improve things by just reading all of the files in the main process (or some other) to get them into RAM. Then each md5'ing process won't have to load from disk *and* md5, it will just have to md5. (Assuming you've got the memory for this, of course.)

Comment: Yeah, I probably would run out of memory as I'm checking a few TB in live cases.  I could try loading chunks at a time though.

Comment: Turns out the bottleneck for my case is IO.  Actually its 23% faster to pipe a find command into an md5 command, than to walk, read, and md5 in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use threads, you need to first initiate your threads and have them poll work off a Queue.Queue instance. Then in your main thread, run through the for-loop you have, but instead of calling md5file(..), push all the arguments on the Queue.Queue.  [Threading / Queue in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074984/threading-queue-in-python) has an example, but look at the docs as well: http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html

Answer (score 0):

Threads would not be very helpful do the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock.) Your application would never execute more than one call to the md5.update function at the same time.  I would continue to try and optimize improve your process pool.

Comment: If md5file reads from disk, this is not true. The GIL is not held during disk IO.  That being said, threading is a better solution to latency problems than to throughput issues...

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm using the wrong terminology.  What I think I want is multiprocessing, not multithreading.  Right?

Comment: It won't make much of a difference if you're heavily IO-bound, but _in_general_ multiprocessing is the right way to utilize more CPU-cores in Python.

Comment: @thebjorn, but the GIL will be locked when you are computing the hash value, which can be much more expensive than IO.

Comment: @mikerobi Nah, nothing is normally more expensive than IO -- seriously :-)  According to Jamie (above) IO accounts for 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Go embarrassingly parallel and start a process for a chunk of files. We do this on clusters. You can have dozens or hundreds of processes each md5ing a few dozen files. At that point, disk IO will be your bottleneck.